# The device GattServer stops advertising after connecting to it

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-things, android-ble

This is the link to the GATT Server sample for Android Things on GitHub:

https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver

Setting up the server on RPi-3 is easy enough.

What I do not understand is why the GATT server stops advertising once you have connected to then disconnected from the device (BLE connect).

```
...gattserver I/GattServerActivity: BluetoothDevice CONNECTED: 67:2F:1A:B4:1F:86
...gattserver D/BluetoothGattServer: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=67:2F:1A:B4:1F:86 interval=6 latency=0 timeout=2000 status=0
...gattserver D/BluetoothGattServer: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=67:2F:1A:B4:1F:86 interval=39 latency=0 timeout=2000 status=0
...gattserver I/GattServerActivity: Read CurrentTime
...gattserver I/GattServerActivity: Read CurrentTime
...gattserver I/GattServerActivity: Read CurrentTime
...gattserver I/GattServerActivity: Read CurrentTime
...gattserver I/GattServerActivity: Read CurrentTime
...gattserver D/GattServerActivity: Config descriptor read
...gattserver I/GattServerActivity: Read LocalTimeInfo
...gattserver D/BluetoothGattServer: onServerConnectionState() - status=0 serverIf=5 device=67:2F:1A:B4:1F:86
...gattserver I/GattServerActivity: BluetoothDevice DISCONNECTED: 67:2F:1A:B4:1F:86
...gattserver I/GattServerActivity: No subscribers registered
```

The above is what shows in the LogCat for the device.
First line shows that my phone was able to connect to the device.
(using this free and excellent app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp )

When connected I can read it's characteristics (Read CurrentType, Read LocalTimeInfo etc.)

When disconnecting the phone/app from the device the GattServerActivity states that I disconnected with grace and keeps on running...

But trying to scan for devices from the phone/app again reveals that the GATT Server on the RPi has gone zombie...

No errors in the LogCat (not in app, not in system)...

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: So the issue is that the GATT server doesn't start advertising again on disconnection? Can you just add a new line [here](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/gattserver/GattServerActivity.java#L317) to start advertising again?

Comment: @Nick Felker I can (and thanks). It's just that I never expected it to stop... Is this normal behavior for BLE advertising?

Comment: I'm not an expert in the BLE behavior, so I do not know if it is intentional. I will check with the sample. But I will reformat the comment above as the canonical answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the GATT server doesn't start advertising again on disconnection? You should be able to add a new line [here](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/gattserver/GattServerActivity.java#L317) to start advertising again.

Comment: I tested the same with my Polar H7, and it has similar behaviour. So answer accepted! Thanks!

Comment: A gatt server is by spec REQUIRED to stop advertising (a connectable advertisement) on connection.

Answer (score 1):

Tried just re-starting advertising, but that didn't work so I stopped and started and that worked. Test on RPi 3B

```
@Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothDevice device, int status, int newState) {
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "BluetoothDevice CONNECTED: " + device);
        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "BluetoothDevice DISCONNECTED: " + device);
            //Remove device from any active subscriptions
            mRegisteredDevices.remove(device);
            stopAdvertising();
            startAdvertising();
        }
    }
```