# Android (Things) GATT server stops advertising

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-things, gatt, disconnect

I'm developing an Android Things app (Dev Preview 6.1, Raspberry Pi) with a GATT server. When a connected client app disconnects, my device has stopped advertising. However, the custom client app (out of my control) is written in such a way that it needs to disconnect between reads/writes, then reconnect.

I know that I can restart advertising upon disconnect, but since it has a new (pseudo-)MAC address, the client can't automatically reconnect.

FWIW, I see the same behavior in this sample (& using nRF Connect as a test clinet): https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver

Is there way to keep the GATT server advertising in this case? Or can I specify the advertised device address so that I can keep it consistent across advertisements?

Comment: This question may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676988/the-device-gattserver-stops-advertising-after-connecting-to-it

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is a known bug in Android Things: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70269277

Comment: @ThomasSmyth I think that this is an actual answer - the answer is that "this is a known bug" and the link is there to provide evidence for that.